# Remove white border in image using Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, border, ghostscript

I needed to parse a PDF file to images using PHP. I've done it with the help of Ghostscript.  Here is the script:

```
$result = exec("gs -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=page-%03d.png $pdfname.pdf");
```

But almost all of the final images have **white borders** around them (PDF pages don't have those borders). How can get rid of them? Maybe there are some methods in Ghostcript code that I couldn't find and which would help.

Here is a image -> http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/88046_page-009.png

Here is a printscreen from a PDF file -> http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/62869_pdf.PNG

Comment: Can you provide sample PDF and JPEG files which exhibit the white borders you describe?

Comment: I've edited a post and there you can find samples

Comment: A printscreen from the PDF isn't good enough. I need to look at the values of `/MediaBox`, `/ArtBox`, `/TrimBox`, `/CropBox` and `/BleedBox` and therefor need to look at the PDF itself. The one page extracted from the PDF which has the picture is probably enough...

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by  /MediaBox, /ArtBox, /TrimBox, /CropBox and /BleedBox...And how do I extract one page from PDF? I would give you the whole PDF file, but I can't distribute it...

Comment: You can use the commandline tool [`pdftk.exe`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/) to extract a page from a PDF. To extract page 9: `pdftk Esquire.pdf cat 9 output p9.pdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that your pages have a CropBox defined which is smaller than the MediaBox. You can tell Ghostscript to use teh CropBox by supplying the -dUseCropBox switch on the command line.

Of course, as Kurt has said, its not really possible to tell without seeing the original file.

Comment: Could you tell me what are those Mediabox and Crobboxes? Or maybe a link where it is written about. And you are saying that you need an original file, why? What would you see in it? Maybe I can can check it if you explain

Comment: You are a genius!!! Thank you very much! Your suggestion was absolutely right! Thanks!

Comment: @PigalevPavel: It's always better to have access to a sample file if one is to give a definite answer about PDF problems. Everything else is just pure speculation.

Comment: I understand it but I just don't know how I can do a saple of PDF without cropping it or printscreening... And anyway the suggestion was right and that os what I needed. And btw Kurt thank you to for helping!

Comment: Thanks you for this, if it helps anyone to do this with Imagemagick you need to add the define at the start of the line.  e.g.
convert -define pdf:use-cropbox=true -density %DENSITY% "%SOURCEPDF%" %GENERATEDLARGEPNG%

Answer (score 2):

Pigalev Pavel should give the real answer about how he solved the problem. One possibility is that he had to use something like:

```
gs                           \
  -sDEVICE=png16m            \
  -sOutputFile=page-%03d.png \
  -dUseTrimBox               \
   file.pdf
```

or

```
gs                           \
  -sDEVICE=png16m            \
  -sOutputFile=page-%03d.png \
  -dUseCropBox               \
   file.pdf
```